# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on string while parsing data

Tags: php, curl, dom, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

So I am trying to get some information from this webpage https://promo.pan.com.hr with curl and simple HTML dom. But unfortunately, I keep receiving an error and I can't figure it out what is wrong...

```
<?php
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}

$html = file_get_contents_curl("https://promo.pan.com.hr");


foreach($html->find("p") as $element)
echo $element->innertext . '<br>';
?>
```

Anyone knows why I am getting this error?

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on string in C:\Server\XAMPP\htdocs\pan\index.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Server\XAMPP\htdocs\pan\index.php on line 21

line 21 is:

```
foreach($html->find("p") as $element)
```

Comment: It will be much easier to help if you post a complete code snippet.

Try printing `$html` to ensure the file is being read?  It looks like you're getting a string rather than HTML.

Comment: this is all the code :)

Comment: EDIT: few lines didn't show, mb, now is showing everything

Comment: file_get_contents_curl returns a string, then you're trying to use it as an object, which is exactly what PHP complains about. and honestly, don't use simple_html_dom, it is obsolete, has been for a long time, use DOMDocument instead. `$html = file_get_contents_curl("https://promo.pan.com.hr");$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);

foreach($domd->getElementsByTagName("p") as $element){
echo $element->textContent. '<br>';
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume `file_get_contents_curl` is the function which returns `$data` above the call to it.

Your problem is that `[curl_exec][1]` returns a string which is the contents of the web page. I presume you are using `simple_html_dom` in which case you need to convert that string into a `simple_html_dom` object first:

```
$html = str_get_html(file_get_contents_curl("https://promo.pan.com.hr"));
```

or you could just use:

```
$html = file_get_html("https://promo.pan.com.hr");
```

and avoid curl altogether.

Comment: this one helps with error but unfortunately, I can only get the title from this page, any solution for that problem?

Comment: If you visit the page in a browser and look at the page source, you'll see all of the HTML is loaded via javascript, which is why all you can see is the title. Unfortunately I don't believe there is any way in PHP to render that. You might try googling "render page in PHP"?

Comment: You might find this article useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085261/crawling-a-website-with-php-but-the-website-runs-js-to-generate-markup

Comment: Thanks again, I was researching a little and found phantom js very useful. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction :)