# Crawling a website with PHP, but the website runs JS to generate markup

Tags: javascript, php, web-crawler

I have been doing webcrawling for the last couple weeks.
Using a PHP library (PHP Simple DOM), im running a php script (using terminal) to fetch some URLs and JSON some data from it. This has been working very nice so far.

Recently i wanted to expand the crawling for a specific site and encountered the following problem:

Unlike any other site so far, this one only echos a barebones markup server side and instead relies  on a single JS script to build up the relevant markup onload.

Obviously my PHP script cant handle that (as it is not executing the JS and hence the site stays mostly blank from what i can tell) and so i cant crawl the site, since the content is not yet created.

Im unsure how to proceed. Is it actually possibly to convert my current PHP script to be "compatible" with that site, or do i need to change gears and incorporate a browser, i.e. pick a completely different route ?

Im currently thinking i would need to create html/js site which opens the URL in an iFrame and that way i could run a JS function manually via the console to extract the data.
However, im hoping there is a more feasible way.

thanks,

Comment: I suppose this problem is to difficult for standalone developer. Google teached their crawler to run JS not so long ago, and they are the only who is successful on it

Comment: You'll need something like phantomjs that can load the page like a browser did, then it's actually really easy. You won't be able to do that with php though, you'll need to use node or python. Don't be distracted by @LevitatorImbalance comment, that's not the case.

Comment: the website you are crawling must have a non-javascript version. Otherwise, the Google bot will see nothing usefull.

Comment: @DanielFaure nope, see "Fetch as Google" feature. Or you can test website https://preactjs.com on the [Google Page Speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) and see that Google perfectly renders JS

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance, thanks for your recommendations. I have to research a lot about this (Im still living in the past). I found a payed tool that performs this kind of crawling, with a very nice introduction. Take a look at [sitebulb.com](https://sitebulb.com/resources/guides/how-to-crawl-javascript-websites/)

Comment: @DanielFaure Thanks for the article, looks interesting, I'll take a look after work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I need to *scrap* a website I normally:

1 - Navigate the *target* website on a normal browser (ff, chrome, etc.), **while monitoring/logging** any `POST`/`GET` requests containing pertinent info via `Developer Tools` -> `Network Tab`.
Pay special attention to `XHR` requests, as they normally contain `json` encoded data.
Here's a small video I've made exemplifying this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbiZBGt8cos

You can *mimic* the `request headers` made  previously (explained in the video) and use it on a `curl` request, i.e.:

```
$headers = [
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36",
    "DNT: 1",
    "Accept-Language: pt,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,pt-PT;q=0.7,pt-BR;q=0.6",
];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://s1te.com/json_rand.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
print  $server_output ;
```

---

2 - In some cases, it's impossible to crawl certain URL's without a **JavaScript Enabled Client**, when this happens, I normally use [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) with `Chrome` or `Firefox`. You can also use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), a headless browser.  Latest versions of [GeckoDriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) (used by Selenium) also support headless browsing.

---

I'm aware the question is about `PHP`, but if the OP needs to use `Selenium`, `Python` is way more intuitive I'd say. Based on that, here's a `Selenium` example in `Python`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

[Example Src](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)

Comment: I picked this answer because even though technically both answers are correct, i found this one to be more helpful especially in regards to Monitoring AJAX and catching any GET / POST Server answers.

Answer (score 2):

I see two possible paths:

- In case the JavaScript that builds up the DOM fetches the data through one or more AJAX calls, you might as well scrape from those URLs directly (and this tends to be easier anyway, e.g. if it talks to a JSON API).
- Simulate a browser, e.g. using Selenium. For example, [this](https://medium.com/@hoppy/how-to-test-or-scrape-javascript-rendered-websites-with-python-selenium-a-beginner-step-by-c137892216aa) article discusses the exact challenge you mention and provides a solution using Selenium and Python.

Comment: And OP should also avoid some possible dangerously parts of JS (assume that developers are bad boys and they included ```while (true) {}``` cycle into their bundle) :)

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance If devs use such "trap", they're website will be also unusable. There's no way to detect is you're dealing with an automated request or a normal user. I've never seen a js trap like this.

Comment: @PedroLobito Intruders usually are nevermind about site usability. OTOH, there are some ways to detect crawler rendering.

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance "***there are some ways to detect crawler rendering***", dozens, but none's reliable.

Comment: @PedroLobito Well, I'm not talking about crawlers detection reliability, I'm talking about possibility of such JS problems as an endless loop or endless recursion, that can shut the crawler's server down. Good JS-executing crawler should consider it :)

Comment: @PedroLobito It's still possible that your crawler renderer does not support or provide a browser feature, which causes the script to do something it wouldn't do otherwise (e.g. infinite loop, hundreds of AJAX requests, etc.).

It's always a smart idea to sandbox and constraint any untrusted code as much as possible.