# PHP Crawl and get all the links on a website that is created with AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, reactjs, vue.js

I am trying to crawl an entire website, I cannot manage to get data on the 2nd level. I cannot find a way to parse the links and get the content of each link.

**PHP crawl website that is created with AngularJS with DOMDocument() or file_get_contents()**

PHP code I have tried is below

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/"
$dom = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->strictErrorChecking = false;
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Normal websites are returning all the links but websites created in Angular/VueJS are not returning any URL ( the links also not visible when viewing page source )

I think more people will be having the same issue. Does anyone have a solution.?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crawling a website with PHP, but the website runs JS to generate markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085261/crawling-a-website-with-php-but-the-website-runs-js-to-generate-markup)

Comment: @bluemoon6790 Here the question is specific to DOMDocument() or file_get_contents() not the curl()

Comment: Your problem isn't that you're using file_get_contents(), your problem is that DOMDocument is not designed to execute JavaScript.